# updateDoc: Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid document reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When updating a document in v9 of `firebase/firestore` I got an error and I've been following the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_8) and not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, updateDoc, doc} from 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from '../utils/firestore';

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

function updateSeries(docID, name, desc) {

    const data = {
        name: name,
        desc: desc,
        lastUpdatedAt: Timestamp.now(),
    }

    const seriesDocRef = doc(db, "MY_COL", docID)


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        updateDoc(seriesDocRef, data).then(() => {
            resolve();
        }).catch((e) => {
            reject(e);
        })
    })
}
```

When I call this function I get this error:

> errors.ts:94 Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but MY_COL has 1.

Comment: Have you defined `db` anywhere? You might have missed the initialization step [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize)

Comment: @bluecouch I have defined it. Forgot to add it to the code. I've updated my question.

Comment: Are both `db` and `docID` defined when the line is run?

Comment: oh forget my comment before. didn't see you appended `docID` after the MY_COL.

Comment: @bluecouch you were right. The `docID` was `""` and fixing it fixed it. You can add this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in passed into the `doc` function are undefined or falsy it can cause this error. Please check if the `db` and `docID` variables are defined in:

```
const seriesDocRef = doc(db, "MY_COL", docID)
```